# testing pallet with ensure_root

Tags: frame, testing, mock

I have written tests.rs and mock.rs

everything is working except a function which has checks for root

```
    pub fn create_something(
        origin: OriginFor<T>,
        org: T::Hash
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        // TODO: ensure origin == controller
        ensure_root(origin)?;
```

My test something like:

```
assert_ok!(MyVeryFirstModuleModule::create_something(Origin::signed(ALICE), H256::random()));
```

If I don't comment ensure_root I am getting Bad_Origin panic.
How can I mock root?

Answer (score 4):

If this is for tests, have you tried using:

```rust
RuntimeOrigin::root()
```

Example here:

```rust
assert_ok!(Balances::set_balance(RuntimeOrigin::root(), 1, 1_000, 0));
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/tests.rs#L828